# function call another without waiting to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my method feedContactCategorySelection, i would like to wait the `assignContactCategoryToLocal` call to be finished before continuing to run the rest of the code

```
feedContactCategorySelection();

function feedContactCategorySelection(){

  assignContactCategoryToLocal();

  var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");

  category = JSON.parse(category);
  for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
    //....
  }
}


function assignContactCategoryToLocal() {

  var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
  if (category == null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (json) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(json));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use a `Promise` and execute the rest of the code in a `onFulfilled` handler

Comment: @LiYinKong - Not if you want your code to work in IE.

Comment: @aroth The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface with `done` and `fail`

Comment: @LiYinKong - Fair enough, the question was only tagged with 'javascript' so I assumed the OP wanted a pure JavaScript (i.e. "framework agnostic") solution.  I've added a 'jquery' tag to the question as the OP's code is clearly using jQuery.

Comment: is the same thing if i want to call many function but wait then all function be finished before running another one? goal is when user is loging to load many data in session storage

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback function to the `assignContactCategoryToLocal()` that way you can continue running the code only when the ajax is done. Something like this:

```
feedContactCategorySelection();

function feedContactCategorySelection() {
    // Do anything here before running the ajax
    // For instance, get category and pass it to the assignContact...
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
    ...
    assignContactCategoryToLocal(category, myCallbackFunction);
}

function myCallbackFunction(category) {
    category = JSON.parse(category);
    for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
        ....
    }
}

function assignContactCategoryToLocal(category, callback) {

    if (category == null) {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function (json) {
              sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(json));
              // Now that it is done and successful, run the rest...
              callback(category);
          }
      });
    }
}
```

For sake of example, you can get the category once and then pass it along the functions, maybe that helps understand how they are connected.

**EDIT:**
To address the issue with the category being `null`, here is a revised version.

```
feedContactCategorySelection();

function feedContactCategorySelection() {
    // Do anything here before running the ajax
    // For instance, get category and pass it to the assignContact...
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
    ...

    // Move the if statement here so it checks the condition earlier.
    if (category === null) {
        assignContactCategoryToLocal(category, myCallbackFunction);
    } else {
        myCallbackFunction(category);
    }
}

function myCallbackFunction(category) {
    category = JSON.parse(category);
    for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
        ....
    }
}

function assignContactCategoryToLocal(category, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (json) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(json));                           
          // Now that it is done and successful, run the rest...
          callback(category);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: there is a problem with this code, if category is null in feedContactCategorySelection, in myCallbackFunction var will have same value.

Comment: Well, not exactly. If the category is `null` the `myCallbackFunction` will never run. That is because you have already set an if statement that checks if the category is `null` before running the ajax. `myCallbackFunction` in this example, will only run if the category is NOT `null` and if the ajax was sucessful. Give it a try and let us know. For an even cleaner code, you could move the `if (category === null) ...` to the `feedContactCategorySelection`. But it should work as it is in the code above.

Comment: Oh you are right, I overlooked your if statement. Why should it run if the category is null? shouldn't it be the other way around? meaning, the conditional should be `if (category !== null) ...` As it is now, the ajax will run only if the category is null.

Comment: i read session storage, if not found, i do ajax call to store value in session storage

Comment: I see now, well perhaps adding an `else` will take care of running the callback when you have retrieved the category from either session storage or through ajax. See edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Promise](https://promisesaplus.com/) in this case.

Pseudocode as below:

```
feedContactCategorySelection();

function feedContactCategorySelection(){

  assignContactCategoryToLocal().then(function(){
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");

    category = JSON.parse(category);
    for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
     ....
    }
  })

}

function assignContactCategoryToLocal() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
  if (category == null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (json) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(json));
            resolve()
        }
        failed:{reject(reason)}
    });
  })    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function feedContactCategorySelection() {    
  // `data` : `sessionStorage.getItem("category")` or response from `$.ajax()`
  assignContactCategoryToLocal().then(function(data) {   
      // if `category` set , return `category` , else set `category`
      var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category") != null 
                     ? sessionStorage.getItem("category") 
                     : sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(data));   
      category = JSON.parse(category);
      for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
        //....
      }
  // handle errors, if any, from `$.ajax()` call
  }, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)
  })
}

function assignContactCategoryToLocal() {
  var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");  
    // if `category` is `null` , return `$.ajax()` response   
    return category == null
       ? $.ajax({
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
           type: 'GET'
         }) 
      : $.when(category)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check i have added `async: false,` to wait until get the ajax response.

```
feedContactCategorySelection();

function feedContactCategorySelection(){

  assignContactCategoryToLocal();

  var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");

  category = JSON.parse(category);
  for (var i = 0; category["data"].length; i++) {
    //....
  }
}


function assignContactCategoryToLocal() {

  var category = sessionStorage.getItem("category");
  if (category == null) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/contact/category',
        type: 'GET', 
        async: false,
        success: function (json) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(json));
        }
    });
}
```